# How to display changeable information at app load

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an app that I want to occasionally display news. I don't want to release an update to the app every time. I thought of having a text file on my website that I read if it exists but I can't get past the HTTP clear text problem in PIE. Is there some smarter way, or some suggestions?

I have tried the `network_security_config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>

    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>

    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">mydomain.org.au</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Specifying
`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in manifest

But the text file does not exist under HTTP
and under HTTPS it exists but read-line comes up null.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by creating a text file on the website.
I then check for the existence of the text file if it is there I copy it to a file on the device and then read it into a `view dialog`.

I do this only once every 48 hours using this

```
if(isOnline(this)){

        long runtime = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getLong("displayedTime", 0);
        if (runtime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 86400000) {  //only display dialog once every two days
            getNews();
            getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .edit()
                    .putLong("displayedTime", System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .commit();
        }


     // if there is a news text file in the root of somedomain.org        
}
```